# When can you cast Flash after casting Collective Voyage?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

After you've cast [Collective Voyage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Collective%20Voyage), do you wait for everyone to pay and then respond with Flash, or do you have to respond immediately?

Comment: What are you asking? What do you want to accomplish? Your question does not make that clear at all.

Answer (score 3):

MtG works by a system of [timing and priority](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Timing_and_Priority). The Active Player, player whose turn it is, can cast Sorceries when the stack is empty during their first or second Main Phase. After casting a spell and paying the required costs, including mana costs, the spell waits on the stack for all players to pass priority, then the top object on the stack resolves.

Casting [Collective Voyage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Collective%20Voyage) for one {G} mana places it on the stack, and then priority is returned to you.

> 116.3c If a player has priority when he or she casts a spell, activates an ability, or takes a special action, that player receives priority afterward.

You may choose to cast [Flash](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flash) before Collective Voyage resolves, in response to it, since Instants may be cast anytime you have priority and you have the required costs including mana cost {1}{U} to cast the spell. In this case, it would resolve first.

> 116.1a A player may cast an instant spell any time he or she has priority. A player may cast a noninstant spell during his or her main phase any time he or she has priority and the stack is empty.

You may also choose to wait until after Collective Voyage resolves, when you will receive priority again to cast spells and activate abilities. In this case, it would resolve afterward.

> 116.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.

> 116.4. If all players pass in succession (that is, if all players pass without taking any actions in between passing), the spell or ability on top of the stack resolves or, if the stack is empty, the phase or step ends.

During the resolution of Collective Voyage, players may not cast spells, but may activate mana abilities to search their library for land cards. The order of how much to pay is written on the card, starting with the player who cast Collective Voyage and continuing clockwise. After all players have decided how much to pay, the lands are placed on the battlefield simultaneously and Collective Voyage is placed in its owner's graveyard (having resolved).

> 116.1d A player may activate a mana ability whenever he or she has priority,whenever he or she is casting a spell or activating an ability that requires a mana payment, or whenever a rule or effect asks for a mana payment (even in the middle of casting or resolving a spell or activating or resolving an ability).

Answer (score 2):

When you play a sorcery, you place the spell on the stack.  Players can then respond with an instant spell or an activated ability.

When nobody responds, or all the responses have resolved, the sorcery will "resolve" in one go.  You cannot respond while a spell is resolving.  That means you can't respond to the first part of the spell, when players pay mana.  The spell will resolve in its entirety.

Only after the entire sorcery is done can you respond again.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

- You can cast [Flash](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flash) (or a card with Flash) in response to the [Collective Voyage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Collective%20Voyage)
- You can cast [Flash](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flash) (or a card with Flash) after [Collective Voyage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Collective%20Voyage) has finished resolving.

---

To cast a spell in response to a spell or ability is to cast a spell after another has been cast but before it resolves.

If you cast Flash in response to Collective Voyage, Flash will resolve before Collective Journey, so Flash will resolve before anyone has payed any mana.

---

After Collective Voyage has finished resolving, players have a change to play spells, starting with the active player (which is likely the one who cast Collective Voyage, since it's a sorcery).

You could cast it then if the Active player declines to cast anything then.